# Django query relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Category',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    metric = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False, null=False)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Category',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to recover all products:

**products = Product.objects.all()**

That's ok. I get all the products with success.

But I want that the products returned came with the ForeignKey attribute as an textual field from the referenced model, and no the raw integer that references it.

The field in question would be the Category.name.

At present my return is:

```
{model: product, pk:1, fields: {..., category: 1} }, { ....... } ...
```

What I Want:

```
{model: product, pk:1, fields: {..., category: 'Categoria 1 '}
```

I need the set pre-populated with the related model info, cause I'll return a JSON string as result for the service caller.

My attempt to return JSON:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
serialized_products = serializers.serialize('json', products)
return JsonResponse({'result': 'success', 'data':serialized_products}) #return all
```

How can I do this? The most simple and elegant form...

Comment: What makes you think the foreign key is not an object?

Comment: @ShangWang I maybe not explained myself properly. In the foreingKey object, I want to return the **Category.name** , but when I query Product.objects.all(), the **category** attribute gives me the integer that corresponds to pointed Category. I'm going to return this as JSON string, so I need this **category.name** allready populated..

Comment: You need to edit your post to show us how did you trying to convert to json.

Comment: Your question makes no sense as written because it is based on a false premise. If you loop over `Product.objects.all()` then each `product.category` will be a Category object, **not** an integer.

Comment: I edited my question, I might be more clear..

Comment: I'm asking you to show the code about **how** did you convert to json, not the actual json you have.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm certainly that I can iterate over the Product.objects.all and construct a new dictionary containing my desired values. My question is if it's possible to do this direct on the "query" . Like if I was doing a JOIN and getting the category.name right on the response of the query, with no need to iterate over the results..

Comment: @ShangWang I'm sorry...I edited now with the info you requested

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is use `values_list` to return whatever fields you want:

```
products = Product.objects.all().values('name', 
                                        'description',
                                        'category__name',
                                        'category__id', 
                                        'category__abbreviation')
return JsonResponse(products)
```

It might be a little less convenient then serializer, but I don't think serializer is good at handling foreigne key relations because what if you have deeper relationships that you need to include in the result?

Comment: Your point is correct. I thought serializers would serialize my "main" objects AND their relationship objects but aparently not. I'll give a try your way.

Comment: @Pavarine I'm not where I can test this right now but what happens if you [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) then serialize?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That was a nice try, but stills dont work. The **select_related** will create the JOINS to fetch all the necessary data from the database at once, but the serializer won't actually "fetch" the returned data and build the related objects.

Comment: Finally I made this, using **natural_keys** for the serializers.. thanks all for the help